# VBScript - Restart another user's explorer.exe

Tags: vbscript, explorer, kill

I'm writing a small VBScript that disables the shut down option in Windows XP start menu on a specific day of the week, then re-enables it the next day. 
The script is meant to be run on a limited privilege user login. Since this user has no permission to alter Windows registry it must be run by an administrator account. 
I set up a scheduled task that runs the script from the administrator account at the limited user login [as explained here, point 5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569/en-us).
Here's the problem: after applying changes to Windows registry, I have to restart that user's explorer.exe for the changes to be effective. My script fails to do this. It can kill explorer.exe but for some reason can't restart it. 
Note that if I run the script directly from the administrator account changing the administrator account's registry setting and restarting the administrator account explorer.exe the script work flawlessly. 
Here's portion of the code:

```
Option Explicit
Const RegKey = "HKEY_USERS\LIMITED USER SID HERE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoClose"   
Const BackupDay = 5  'sunday = 1
Dim WshShell

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If Weekday(Date) = BackupDay Then 

    If WshShell.RegRead(RegKey) = 0 Then

        WshShell.Run "msg * __Message Here__"
        Wscript.Sleep 500

        WshShell.RegWrite RegKey, 1, "REG_DWORD"

        RestartExplorer1
        ' RestartExplorer2 

        WScript.quit

    Else
```

[...]

```
Sub RestartExplorer1()

Dim strComputer, strProcessToKill, objWMIService, colProcess, objProcess

strComputer = "."
strProcessToKill = "explorer.exe"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
    & strComputer _ 
    & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & strProcessToKill & "'")

For Each objProcess in colProcess
    objProcess.Terminate()

Next
End Sub
```

Procedure RestartExplorer1 should kill all explorer.exe processes (including the administrator's one, it's OK as he should be logged off so there shouldn't be one, besides I could filter by username and kill only the user's one but that's not the problem) but does absolutely nothing if run from the scheduled task from administrator account.
RestartExplorer2 has no better luck:

```
Sub RestartExplorer2()

WshShell.Run "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.Run "cmd /c Start explorer.exe"

End Sub
```

In this case explorer.exe is indeed killed but for some reason it isn't restarted.
I searched everywhere with no results. 
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the Explorer.exe process under another user account by using the RunAs feature in Windows.  Try this:

```
Dim objShell, strUsername, strPassword
strUsername = "username"
strPassword = "password"

Set objShell= WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "runas /user:" & strusername & " ""explorer.exe"""

WScript.Sleep 100

objShell.Sendkeys strPassword & "~"
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Hi Nilpo, thank you for your help. Unfortunately runas is not the solution to my problem, I already tried that way without results.